# What is the right way to input a "normal" vector into a MLP and receiving *one* output value as a result?

Tags: python, keras, multidimensional-array, deep-learning

I built this simple Neural Network in Keras, however I don't understand the output of certain input vectors. To illustrate:

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

#Reshape to be 2D:
X = X.reshape(1,-1)

# Create the model
model_mlp = Sequential()
model_mlp.add(Dense(5, input_shape=(X.shape[0],X.shape[1]), activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model_mlp.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

print(model_mlp(X))
```

We are feeding a `(1,5)`-dimensional tensor to the MLP, which outputs one value in the forward pass, as expected. However, if we reshape the tensor to be `(5,1)`, the forward pass outputs 5 values. How can this be?

What is the right way to input a "normal" vector into a MLP and receiving *one* output value as a result?

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that the first dimension is the number of samples, so (1,5) and (5,1) are not the same thing

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Dr.Snoopy! That already clarified everything to me!